# Perl Regexp modifiers "/d" and "/a" are mutually exclusive

Tags: regex, xml, perl

I am trying to read XML data from the serial port using Perl.
I am getting multiple XML responses, some are full and some are half XML responses. In between, I need to check the data which is present in the xyz node.. For that I have written the below line of code

```
if($response =~ /((<data>)(.*)(</data>)/){
    # Process element here
    $data = $0;

}
```

But I get the error Perl Regexp modifiers "/d" and "/a" are mutually exclusive

Request to suggest any solution that I can get to work with.

Regards
Jnaneswar

Comment: Syntax highlighting gives you a big clue here...notice that `/data)/` is highlighted in red. You need to escape any slashes you want to include in your pattern.

Comment: Or you can use a different regex delimeter, if it helps readability. Also `$0` returns the name of the perl file, not the matched string. Newer versions of Perl no longer support its use for regexes.

Comment: Also: Don't regex XML. It's dirty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to escape the delimiter character (here `/`) inside the regular expression.

```
/(<data>)(.*?)(<\/data>)/s
```

Note also:

- In your expression there's also an opening bracket in excess.
- `.*` shoud be ungreedy for the case you have twice `</data>` in your text.
- `/s` allows the `.` to match newlines.

Comment: likely it should be `.*?` instead of `.*`, to stop capturing at the first `</data>`, not the last one.  also, if there are newlines in the data to capture, it should use /s or do `((?s:.*?))`